# Zuul is unable to fetch microservices instance list from Eureka

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am trying to configure Zuul with Eureka with following Zuul auto configuration (Spring Boot):

```
zuul.ignoredServices: '*'
zuul.routes.service1.path: /test/**
zuul.routes.service1.serviceId: CUSTOMER-SERVICE
zuul.routes.service1.stripPrefix: false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled=true
server.port=9090
```

But while making call to CUSTOMER-SERVICE through Zuul getting following exception:

```
com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: CUSTOMER-SERVICE
```

I have checked the Eureka for CUSTOMER-SERVICE with web console, I found an instance of  CUSTOMER-SERVICE registered there correctly.

Can any one help me to know what went wrong?

Comment: how are you making the request?

Comment: I am using web browser (http://localhost:9090/test) for making http request ZUUL proxy. At ZUUL side I have not added anything apart of auto-configuration listed above. It seems ZUUL query Eureka for listed services, but did not get correct response. Please consider following console log.                              `--- [nio-9090-exec-4] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : Client:CUSTOMER-SERVICE instantiated a LoadBalancer:DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=CUSTOMER-SERVICE,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed It is happening because of 
***zuul.routes.service1.stripPrefix: false***
after removing this property application started working as desired.